# AVfoundation in swift - how to include multiple file types

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to have my code search for more than one file type (mp3 and wav as well as the flac) but I can't figure out how to structure this. At the moment I have:

```
for song in songPath
{
    var mySong = song.absoluteString
    if mySong.contains (".flac")
```

and

```
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: "flac")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` collection class and `filter` method:

```
let fileTypes = Set(["flac", "mp3", "wav"])
let filesToPlay = songPath.filter {fileTypes.contains($0.pathExtension)}
```

For example if you have `songPath` defined like that:

`let songPath = [URL(string:"audio/blah.flac")!, URL(string:"audio/fdfd.mp3")!, URL(string:"audio/ggg.ogg")!]`

Than `print(filesToPlay)` will print:

> [audio/blah.flac, audio/fdfd.mp3]